# Interval fasting - is it healthy?

Tags: fasting

According to [Hottenrott 2017](https://www.karger.com/Article/Abstract/480114) (a teaching sport medicine professor), interval fasting is a good for health and losing weight, side effect people feel well and clear.

What are risks though, and is it ok to do this for long time.. years?